# How can I use conditionally make an API call using AXIOS?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

I'm using AXIOS with REACTjs
I want a functionality that if my first API(`GET`) call returns `Not Found`
status code then I want to send the other call efficiently.
Although I'm getting some data through that `.catch` method in form of `Promise<pending>` .Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don’t you add a conditional in the catch block to check the status?

For example:

```
axios.get('/first-call')
  .then(resp => { 
     //handle successful response
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 404) {
     // make second API call
    }
  });
```